# Make variable amount of thumbnails in bootstrap same height using content from database

Tags: css, ejs

[Screenshot of Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxhGP.jpg) I am trying to recreate a pc part picker type of application using bootstrap and express. When trying to display all the cases available on "my" website, I am loading all of the cases from my database in an ejs file and then displaying them in a thumbnail with four in each row. I have used flexboxes on every four elements to make the heights for all thumbnails in one row the same, however it only works on the first row and does not work after. I have tried to add the code underneath, however this is my first time asking a question so if you have any suggestions to make it more readable please do let me know. I have also included the link to the picture of the page at the beginning of the paragraph.

```
    <% var start = 0 %>
    <% cases.forEach(function(qcase) { %>
        <% if (start % 4 == 0) { %>
            <div class="row text-center display-flex">
        <% }; %>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="<%=qcase.image%>">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4><%=qcase.name%></h4>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="/cases/<%=qcase.id%>" class="btn btn-primary">More Information</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <% if (start % 4 == 3) { %>
            </div> 
        <% }; %>  
            <% start += 1 %>  
    <% }); %>
```

Comment: set `max-height` of your images, like `.thumbnail > img { max-height: 100px; }`

Comment: That made it closer, but it did not fully fix it, because the first thumbnail of the second row has a two line name. Also is there no way to do it dynamically, without hard coding the max height beforehand? Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. I tested your code on jsfiddle and it worked fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/d4uzyseq/26/